# Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop Remote Access Windows

Tags: remote-desktop

How can I access my Ubuntu 18.04 desktop server with Windows? Which RDP and VNC are best suited?

Answer (score 0):

I've been using RealVNC for a while now on mutliple platforms. For a VNC connection, definitely consider it. You can download it from [here](https://www.realvnc.com/en/connect/download/viewer/windows/). It supports all common platforms including Windows, Mac, Linux, Android, iOS etc. Install RealVNC *viewer* on Windows, and RealVNC *server* on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The remote access programs are good if you have a complicated password because I have had cases that have hacked servers for these programs. After these attacks I started using anydesk and teamviewer (it is paid, the free version is useful if you connect a few times during the month) for my remote connection.

The programs that serve with the identification of the IP of my computer do not serve me because it is very easy to guess.

So, if you want to use remote access programs use long and complicated passwords, point them in a file where you organize yourself and put the file password.

Why do I use these programs? However simple it may be, they create an identification and random passwords that are changing, that if you want you can make them static, adding a password that only you know and the password that the program gives you will continue to change.

This is just my opinion, the decision is yours.